# Entity framework - Inheritance for tables

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

How can I manage the two following tables in Entity Framework :

---

### Order

- OrderId
- ProductId
- Date

and

---

### OrderArchive

- OrderId
- ProductId
- Date

In this schema orders are periodically transfered from the table Order to the table OrderArchive...
Neither Table Per Type nor Table Per Hierarchy seems to fit my needs... I want to share the same methods for both object types.

Note that I cannot change the database schema.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you can't change the Database schema, ... you've got a huge limitation !

If you could change that, I would do an (abstract) `OrderBase` class, with the common Properties and Methods, and make `Order` and `OrderArchive` inherit from it.

But if you can't, the only thing I see (someone has maybe a better idea) would be

create an interface IOrder

```
public Interface IOrder {
   int OrderId {get;set;}
   int ProductId {get;set;}
   int Date {get;set;}
}
```

make `Order` and `OrderArchive` implement `IOrder` (that won't change Database schema)

and create an helper class with common methods.

```
public static class IOrderHelper {
   //a fake method
   public static IList<IOrder> GetOrderByDate(IEnumerable<IOrder> orderList, DateTime dt) {
       return orderList.Where(m => m.Date.Date == dt);
    }
}
```

But of course, inheritance would be much cleaner, in this case.

**EDIT**
Maybe look for Table per Concrete Type : you might be able to inherit from an abstract class, which wouldn't be mapped in db, and your Database wouldn't be changed.

With Code First, you would have to do

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
    .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("Orders");
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
modelBuilder.Entity<ArchiveOrder>()
    .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("ArchiveOrders");
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
```

but I don't know what you're using (CodeFirst, ModelFirst, DatabaseFirst) ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer

I did not know the Table Per Concrete type and I followed this documentation http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx and it is almost perfect...
But using this method I cannot retrieve records of both tables in a single query (without using a UNION) ?

Comment: @user1756338 that's the counterpart, yes. But if you won't change your db structure... no choice !